# GKE standard persistent disk is not mounting

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

From some time on our kubernetes cluster we could not mount any standard-rwo persistent disk, even freshly created. Upgrade GKE cluster to 1.25.10-gke.2700 didn`t help
For example prometheus stack dynamic PV:

```
kubectl get pv
NAME                                       CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS   CLAIM                                                                                                                    STORAGECLASS   REASON   AGE
pvc-835b43a5-56b3-4811-8641-a6484d82af94   5Gi        RWO            Delete           Bound    kube-monitoring/prometheus-grafana                                                                                       standard-rwo            10m
pvc-cf74cd43-bb11-458c-90f7-2cfe2fcf8f51   30Gi       RWO            Delete           Bound    kube-monitoring/prometheus-prometheus-kube-prometheus-prometheus-db-prometheus-prometheus-kube-prometheus-prometheus-0   standard-rwo            10m
```

```
kubectl get pvc -n kube-monitoring
NAME                                                                                                     STATUS   VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
prometheus-grafana                                                                                       Bound    pvc-835b43a5-56b3-4811-8641-a6484d82af94   5Gi        RWO            standard-rwo   12m
prometheus-prometheus-kube-prometheus-prometheus-db-prometheus-prometheus-kube-prometheus-prometheus-0   Bound    pvc-cf74cd43-bb11-458c-90f7-2cfe2fcf8f51   30Gi       RWO            standard-rwo   11m
```

```
Events:
  Type     Reason                  Age                  From                     Message
  ----     ------                  ----                 ----                     -------
  Normal   Scheduled               4m32s                default-scheduler        Successfully assigned kube-monitoring/prometheus-grafana-f8bc76bb7-55lgt to gke-dev-wp-hosting-manage-pool-nat-5e3cde5c-19k6
  Normal   SuccessfulAttachVolume  4m27s                attachdetach-controller  AttachVolume.Attach succeeded for volume "pvc-835b43a5-56b3-4811-8641-a6484d82af94"
  Warning  FailedMount             14s (x2 over 2m29s)  kubelet                  Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[storage], unattached volumes=[sc-datasources-volume config sc-dashboard-provider storage kube-api-access-6hgdb sc-dashboard-volume]: timed out waiting for the condition
  Warning  FailedMount             7s (x10 over 4m23s)  kubelet                  MountVolume.MountDevice failed for volume "pvc-835b43a5-56b3-4811-8641-a6484d82af94" : rpc error: code = Internal desc = Failed to format and mount device from ("/dev/disk/by-id/google-pvc-835b43a5-56b3-4811-8641-a6484d82af94") to ("/var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/csi/pd.csi.storage.gke.io/4940624ccce6daf2ad2958c9e49dc6e1a6249274233f0c2ab90018bee6468ea3/globalmount") with fstype ("ext4") and options ([]): mount failed: exit status 32
Mounting command: mount
Mounting arguments: -t ext4 -o defaults /dev/disk/by-id/google-pvc-835b43a5-56b3-4811-8641-a6484d82af94 /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/csi/pd.csi.storage.gke.io/4940624ccce6daf2ad2958c9e49dc6e1a6249274233f0c2ab90018bee6468ea3/globalmount
Output: mount: /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/csi/pd.csi.storage.gke.io/4940624ccce6daf2ad2958c9e49dc6e1a6249274233f0c2ab90018bee6468ea3/globalmount: cannot mount /dev/sdb read-only.
```

```
kubectl get pv pvc-835b43a5-56b3-4811-8641-a6484d82af94 -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  annotations:
    pv.kubernetes.io/provisioned-by: pd.csi.storage.gke.io
    volume.kubernetes.io/provisioner-deletion-secret-name: ""
    volume.kubernetes.io/provisioner-deletion-secret-namespace: ""
  creationTimestamp: "2023-08-03T07:50:06Z"
  finalizers:
  - kubernetes.io/pv-protection
  - external-attacher/pd-csi-storage-gke-io
  name: pvc-835b43a5-56b3-4811-8641-a6484d82af94
  resourceVersion: "404236306"
  uid: 07fc6f01-8449-4fef-ad2a-dcbd04a46831
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  claimRef:
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
    name: prometheus-grafana
    namespace: kube-monitoring
    resourceVersion: "404236229"
    uid: 835b43a5-56b3-4811-8641-a6484d82af94
  csi:
    driver: pd.csi.storage.gke.io
    fsType: ext4
    volumeAttributes:
      storage.kubernetes.io/csiProvisionerIdentity: 1691044660229-8081-pd.csi.storage.gke.io
    volumeHandle: projects/xxx/zones/us-central1-f/disks/pvc-835b43a5-56b3-4811-8641-a6484d82af94
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: topology.gke.io/zone
          operator: In
          values:
          - us-central1-f
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Delete
  storageClassName: standard-rwo
  volumeMode: Filesystem
status:
  phase: Bound
```

```
kubectl get pvc prometheus-grafana -n kube-monitoring -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: prometheus
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: kube-monitoring
    pv.kubernetes.io/bind-completed: "yes"
    pv.kubernetes.io/bound-by-controller: "yes"
    volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-provisioner: pd.csi.storage.gke.io
    volume.kubernetes.io/selected-node: gke-dev-wp-hosting-manage-pool-nat-5e3cde5c-19k6
    volume.kubernetes.io/storage-provisioner: pd.csi.storage.gke.io
  creationTimestamp: "2023-08-03T07:49:59Z"
  finalizers:
  - kubernetes.io/pvc-protection
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: prometheus
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: grafana
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 10.0.2
    helm.sh/chart: grafana-6.58.4
  name: prometheus-grafana
  namespace: kube-monitoring
  resourceVersion: "404236299"
  uid: 835b43a5-56b3-4811-8641-a6484d82af94
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
  storageClassName: standard-rwo
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  volumeName: pvc-835b43a5-56b3-4811-8641-a6484d82af94
status:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  phase: Bound
```

tried to purge helm charts and install again. Same thing.
Even with manual setup for any Persistent volume with standard-rwo same issue

Comment: By any chance are you trying to mount the disk which is in `ReadOnly` mode? Share your PVC and PV yaml output.

Comment: Updated my question. Its dynamic provisioned PV (not manually created)

Comment: Command or values.yaml possible to share have to replicate and check.